# How To add another class to an element

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have the following image tag with a class name "kiwi" though i have another class which makes the image spin . i want to toggle this class (called 'elem') when i click on the play button of my  music player

this is the image tage with the class

```
<img src="./images/kiwi.png" class="kiwi" aria-hidden="true" />
```

i want to do

```
<img src="./images/kiwi.png" class="kiwi **elem**" aria-hidden="true" />
```

and this is the play button which should add 'elem' class to the image tag onced clicked

```
<button onclick="justplay()" id="play"><i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

here is the script for play button

```js
let play = document.querySelector("#play");

function playsong() {
    track.play();
    Playing_song = true;
    play.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-pause" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
}
```

[I want the round image to spin when play button is pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N732l.png)

I tried googling this but i could not figure it out with classList

Comment: `play.classList.add(class1,class2)` . for toggle class `play.classList.toggle(class1)`

Comment: but how does this apply on to the **<img class = "class1 class2" />** ?

Comment: `let img = document.querySelector("img");  img.classList.add(class1,class2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its for one element:

```js
let el = document.querySelector('.kiwi')

el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.target.classList.toggle('elem')
    })
```

```css
.elem{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
  <ul>
      <li class="kiwi">1</li>
  </ul>
```

if you have more .kiwi you need to querySelectorAll and use forEach to add eventListener like THIS:

```js
let el = document.querySelectorAll('.kiwi')

el.forEach((item, index) => {item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        el.forEach((toRemove) => {
            toRemove.classList.remove('elem')
        })
        e.target.classList.toggle('elem')
    })
})
```

```css
.elem{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
  <ul>
      <li class="kiwi">1</li>
      <li class="kiwi">2</li>
      <li class="kiwi">3</li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a class to an element, do this:

```
element.classList.add('elem')
```

Further reading about the [classList property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).